# action button and php - doesn' show in the inbox

Tags: php, google-schemas

i'm using phpmailer to send email to me and i even use DKIM with my
google apps account, even the docs says:

> You can easily test if your markup is working
>   correctly end-to-end by sending emails with schemas to your Gmail
>   account. All emails where the sender and the recipient are the same
>   account ignore the registration requirements and can be used for
>   self-testing.

I tryed to send to me, send to another gmail account and nothing.
used the example here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/apps-script-tutorial
and worked great, try to use it in my code and nothing.
is there any restriction using localhost even phpmailer is set to google server: smtp.gmail.com ?

i'm using this code:

```
<?php
require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$content =
'
<html>
  <head>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "action": {
    "@type": "ConfirmAction",
    "name": "Approve Expense",
    "handler": {
      "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
      "url": "https://myexpenses.com/approve?expenseId=abc123"
    }
  },
  "description": "Approval request for Johns $10.13 expense for office supplies"
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      This a test for a Go-To action in Gmail.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
';

echo mailer("mymail","mymail","My Name","test action", $content);


function mailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) { 
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    //$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Username = 'mymail';  
    $mail->Password = 'pass';       
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->isHTML(true); 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        return $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to test the GMail custom actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952662/unable-to-test-the-gmail-custom-actions)

Comment: i did use dkim not like the other question, smtp will not work ? how can i email my self and test this ?

Comment: Please add the email headers to your post so that we can check the DKIM signature.