# How to test Go-To Actions using Laravel?

Tags: google-schemas

I'm trying to implement Go-To Actions and it only works when I use Apps Script. Is it possible to test it from Laravel using gmail account?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you should add the markup as you are doing it in Apps Script example and send it to yourself.

For testing it will only work if authenticated user sends the email to its own account, here you can find more information. https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema

Comment: I did setup Gmail SMTP in Laravel mail.php and I send it to myself but it wont show the button (I used same markup for email). I looked at source and it is not DKIM signed, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Did a little more research and found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952662/unable-to-test-the-gmail-custom-actions  apparently yes it need to be DKIM signed