# Sending emails with Google Markup in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gmail, actionmailer, google-schemas

I'm trying to setup [Gmail's Email Markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup) but I'm not able to test it in my Rails application.

To test it, I have changed my ActionMailer SMTP settings to be as follows:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => 'gmail.com',
    :user_name => 'my_email@gmail.com',
    :password => '[REDACTED]',
    :authentication => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

My Mailer sets up the default `from` and `to` addresses, and defines a method `mail_action` as follows:

```
# app/mailers/test_mailer.rb
class TestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "my_email@gmail.com"
  default to:   "my_email@gmail.com"

  def mail_action
    @data = confirm_action

    mail subject: "Mail action"
  end

  def confirm_action
    {
      "@context" => "http://schema.org",
      "@type" => "EmailMessage",
      "action" => {
        "@type" => "ConfirmAction",
        "name" => "Confirm registration",
        "handler" => {
          "@type" => "HttpActionHandler",
          "url" => "http://google.fr",
        },
      },
    }
  end
end
```

The method `confirm_action` defines the markup for my action, following [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/one-click-action).

In the view for the `mail_action` method, I add the markup in the `<head>`:

```
# app/views/test_mailer/mail_action.html.haml
!!! Strict
%html
  %head
    %title Mail Action

    = content_tag :script, type: 'application/ld+json' do
      = JSON.generate(@data).html_safe

  %body
    %h1 Mail Action
    %pre
      = JSON.generate(@data).html_safe
```

I simply send the email from the Rails console using `TestMailer.mail_action.deliver`.
In the email I receive, I can clearly see the markup, however the action button is not here:

```
Return-Path: <my_email@gmail.com>
Received: from gmail.com ([REDACTED IP ADDRESS])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id qg11sm20491658wic.17.2014.12.17.03.07.30
        for <my_email@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 17 Dec 2014 03:07:36 -0800 (PST)
Date: Wed, 17 Dec 2014 12:07:29 +0100
From: my_email@gmail.com
To: my_email@gmail.com
Message-ID: <549163f154ad5_3a153fea39063bec467c7@Pluto.mail>
Subject: Mail action
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mail Action</title>
    <script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"EmailMessage","action":{"@type":"ConfirmAction","name":"Confirm registration","handler":{"@type":"HttpActionHandler","url":"http://google.fr"}}}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Mail Action</h1>
    <pre>{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"EmailMessage","action":{"@type":"ConfirmAction","name":"Confirm registration","handler":{"@type":"HttpActionHandler","url":"http://google.fr"}}}</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Gmail Inbox]

Does anyone know what I'm missing / doing wrong ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send test emails, even to yourself, the emails need to be signed with  DKIM/SPF to prevent spoofing as mention in this question: [Unable to test the GMail custom actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952662/unable-to-test-the-gmail-custom-actions)

You can test your markup sending and email to yourself with Apps Script. When the markup is well tested, you can then register with Google. Here is the information needed https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google#registration_guidelines

Comment: Unfortunately, my markup is generated depending on the context. Is there any way to sign the emails without using Apps Script ?

Comment: I found this link https://support.google.com/a/answer/174124?hl=en&ref_topic=2752442&rd=1 
I hope it helps you